# kmeans pyspark org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I want to use the k-means on my base (6,7 million rows and 22 variables),

`base.dtypes`

```
 ('anonimisation2', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation3', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation4', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation5', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation6', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation7', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation8', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation9', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation10', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation11', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation12', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation13', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation14', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation15', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation16', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation17', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation18', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation19', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation20', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation21', 'double'),
 ('anonimisation22', 'double')]
```

I read that I should use this code :

```
def transData(base):
    return base.rdd.map(lambda r: [Vectors.dense(r[:-1])]).toDF(['features'])
```

```
transformed= transData(base)
transformed.show(5, False)
```

then I wrote this :

```
kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(transformed)
```

and I have this error :

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column features must be of type equal to one of the following types: [struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>, array<double>, array<float>] but was actually of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.'
```

Don't know what to do with it ?
If you want more information just ask
thank's

I tried to go on Pandas to use python but I also had issues there

Comment: Post a full stacktrace here, please, otherwise it's impossible to understand, what was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors` instead of `from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors`